# Pandas list comprehension to change integers in df

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm trying to alter data in a pandas df. Using below, where `X >=5`, I want to change corresponding `Y` row to `1`. Where `X <= -5`, I want to change corresponding `Y` `0`.

```
# Generate random data
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('X'))
df['X2'] = np.random.randint(1, 20, df.shape[0])
df['Y'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, df.shape[0])

df['Y'] = [y if y <= 5 else 1 for y in df['X']]
df['Y'] = [y if y >= -5 else 0 for y in df['X']]
```

Out:

```
   X  X2  Y
0  5  11  5
1  5  13  5
2  5   5  5
3 -7   3  0
4  2   8  2
5 -7   7  0
6 -4   2 -4
7  1   8  1
8 -7  14  0
9 -2   8 -2
```

Intended:

```
   X  X2  Y
0  5  11  1
1  5  13  1
2  5   5  1
3 -7   3  0
4  2   8  Original random int
5 -7   7  0
6 -4   2  Original random int
7  1   8  Original random int
8 -7  14  0
9 -2   8  Original random int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['Y'] = np.where(df['X'].ge(5),1,df['Y'])
df['Y'] = np.where(df['X'].le(-5),0,df['Y'])
```

---

Even better, for multiple conditions, use `np.select`:

```
conditions=[df['X'].ge(5),df['X'].le(-5)]
choices=[1,0]
df['Y']=np.select(conditions,choices,default=df['Y'])
```

---

Or, if you only want to do it with a list comprehension, use `zip`:

```
df['Y'] =[1 if x>=5 else(0 if x<=-5 else y)for x,y in zip(df['X'],df['Y'])]
```

---

Output:

```
original df
   X  X2  Y
0  -6  11  1
1 -10  10  0
2   6  15  1
3   9  12  0
4  -2   3  1
5  -5   2  0
6   5   6  1
7  -1  12  0
8   7  10  0
9  -6   9  0

df after np.where
    X  X2  Y
0  -6  11  0
1 -10  10  0
2   6  15  1
3   9  12  1
4  -2   3  1
5  -5   2  0
6   5   6  1
7  -1  12  0
8   7  10  1
9  -6   9  0
```

Comment: Nice. So if I included a separate condition incorporating `X2`, it may be more efficient to use a `where` statement? For instance, `1 if x >5 in X and <= 15 in X2`.

Comment: I think it's better to use `np.where`, because, the list comprehension with a lot of conditions won't be so readable and you will have to make the zip larger, while with `np.where` you only have to concatenate the conditions with bitwise operators and that's all. @jonboy

Comment: @MrNobody33 `numpy.select` will allow you to account for both conditions in one function call

Comment: @PaulH - Yes, that's true, I was thinking of adding it when the answer was accepted, and I didn't. But now that you mention it, and also that the OP is thinking about adding more conditions, I'll add the solution with `np.select` which will fit more to the problem. Thank you

Comment: To incorporate `X2`, better use `np.select` ;), see the edited answer @jonboy